# jQuery Assigning DOM element to an object

Tags: jquery, object

In the given scenario, how would I assign a DOM object to a variable and call to it? In this example I am trying to get "nav" elements height. Right now it is not returning any values and I am thinking it is because the element is called before the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready( function(){ 
    gbe.init();
});


var gbe = {

    navigation  : $("nav"),

    init    :   function() {
        gbe.nav.init();
    },

    nav     :   {

        init : function() {
            navHeight : gbe.navigation.height(); 
            console.log(gbe.nav.init.navHeight, gbe.navigation.height());
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: You're using `.ready()`, so the DOM is as ready as it's going to get...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you did this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){ 
  gbe.navigation = $("nav");
  gbe.init();
});
```

Comment: Yes, I am using the HTML5 tag "nav", but it has to work for any element required.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your $(document).ready below the definition for gbe.   Only the second entry in your console.log statement will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
​$(document).ready(function() {
    var $nav = $("nav");
    var height = $nav.height();
    console.log(height);
});​
```

Are you attempting a revealing module pattern? The code above is the quick and dirty way.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/jhZSG/

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should pass the element(s) via jQuery to the init function, and pass it on .ready() like this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){ 
    gbe.init($("nav"));
});

var gbe = {    

    init    :   function(el) {
        gbe.navigation : el,
        gbe.nav.init();
    },

    nav     :   {

        init : function() {
            navHeight : gbe.navigation.height(); 
            console.log(gbe.nav.init.navHeight, gbe.navigation.height());
        }
    }

};
```